# Como transformar um set em lista Python 3.x

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um exercício que pede para, dado dois sets, printar em ordem crescente (linha por linha) a diferença simétrica entre eles, meu código:

```py
n = set(input().split())
m = set(input().split())

m_diff = m.difference(n)
n_diff = n.difference(m)
result = [m_diff, n_diff]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(0, len(result)):
        print(result[i])
```

input:

```
2 4 5 9
2 4 11 12
```

meu output:

```
{'11', '12'}
{'9', '5'}
```

output esperado:

```
5
9
11
12
```

Como eu faço pra tirar os elementos de dentro dos sets e fazer todos eles virarem elementos de apenas uma mesma lista?

Comment: Não ocorreu isto porque você colocou assim `result = [m_diff, n_diff]`? Porque ai nem foi a questão de transformar em set, foi simplesmente que pegou os "diffs" e colocou um no index 0 e outro no index 1, isso tudo já sabendo que o `.difference` retorna todos resultados que diferem em um novo `set`, pois bem, se quer juntar tudo o correto me parece que seria o `.union` (acho não tenho certeza) ou o `.update` ou o "pipe" (`set1|set2`)

Comment: o problema que o difference() retorna um set, eu pus numa lista pra poder dar .sort() e printar item por item em order crescente, igual aparece no output esperado

Comment: Eu disse no começo, o problema não parece no resto do código e nem no difference, parece no `result = [m_diff, n_diff]`, vou usou um `[...,...]` quando talvez deveria ter usado union ou update, depende do que deseja

Comment: Você tinha razão, com o update retorna o set  completo {'4', '12', '9', '11'}, agora como faço para dar print em cada elemento do set?

Comment: Pega o set que foi atualizado, afinal essa é diferença do .update() pro .union(), não é? Não me lembro ao certo. Se usou o update um dos seus sets foi atualizado, então um deles tem todos valores

Comment: sim, o update() transformou tudo num set apenas, com todos os elementos que me interessaram, mas nao se pode iterar e print como numa lista, nem usar o sort(). Ainda me falta saber como retornar o output esperado

Comment: Não está iterando o `set`? acho que é só usar `for i in m_diff` ou `for i in n_diff` (dependendo de qual recebeu o update)

Comment: Iterar usando o índice não é o jeito mais idiomático de se iterar em `Python`. O jeito proposto pelo @GuilhermeNascimento, entretanto, com `for var in iterable` é o mais idiomático e permite iterar de diversas maneiras

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, o método de vocês não precisou transformar em list, eu não sabia que se podia iterar ali. De qualquer forma, a jus do título vou responder à pergunta convertendo o set em list primeiro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o método da classe `set` de [`diferença simétrica`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference):

```
result = m.symmetric_difference(n)
```

Ou o operador equivalente `^`:

```
result = m ^ n
```

Por exemplo:

```
a = '2 4 5 9'
b = '2 4 11 12'

n = set(int(i) for i in a.split())
m = set(int(i) for i in b.split())

result = m ^ n

for i in sorted(result):
    print(i)
```

Saída:

```
5
9
11
12
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FreeDarkvioletJavabytecode)

Comment: a saída tem que ser em ordem crescente: ```for i in sorted(list(result), key=int):
print(i)```

Comment: @Pirategull: Feito!

Answer (score 0):

```py
n2 = set(input().split())
m2 = set(input().split())

m_diff = m2.difference(n2)
n_diff = n2.difference(m2)

# poderia resolver o exercício iterando diretamente no set e usando print()
m_diff.update(n_diff)


# esse método converte set em list:
def convert(set):
    return list(set)

#set convertido para lista
m_lis = convert(m_diff) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for elements in m_lis:
        print(elements)
```